# What does a random walk do exactly?

Tags: time-series, biostatistics, bioinformatics

To be honest, I have read many websites and answers regarding to this question, and none explained it in simple words which are understandable. What I want to do is to understand what a random walk does, and how it can be used for Gene Set Enrichment Analysis.

There is a published paper here http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3205944/ however, I could not really understand it.

Can someone please explain what it does in simple words?

Comment: Those are two *very* different questions!

Comment: @Alexis I accepted your revise, I hope now it is clear !

Comment: @Nemo I removed unrelated tags and added [tag:time-series] tag. Feel free to edit my changes or add additional tags but tags like [tag:r], [tag:statistical-significance], or [tag:mathematics] seem unrelated in here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am going to try and answer your first question

**A random walk is a series of measurements in which the value at any given point in the series is the value of the previous point in the series plus some random quantity.**

For example, suppose you flip a fair coin in a series of tosses, and every time the coin comes up heads you *add 1* to the previous value of your serial variable, and every time the coin comes up tails you *subtract 1* from the previous value of your serial variable. If the starting value is 0, and if you flip the following sequence of coin tosses:

```
T H T T T H H H T T H T H T H
```

The the *random walk*, $y$ based on these values as described above would be:

```
0 -1 0 -1 -2 -3 -2 -3 -1 -2 -2 -1 -2 -1 -2 -1
```

So the value of $y$ is:

$$y_{t} = y_{t-1} + 2\mathcal{Bernoulli}(0.5)–1$$

The distribution of $y$ is dependent on time $t$, giving some interesting properties to a sample of $y$ across different times:

1. **The *mean* of $y$ is undefined.** This may seem counter-intuitive, since you might expect that the heads and tails of a balanced coin are centered on zero. This is true as far as it goes, *but zero was just an arbitrary starting value of $y$.* So there's no real mean!
2. **The *variance* of $y=t$.** As time (the number of flips) increases, the variance also increases. For example, at the first flip ($t=1$), the possible values are $1$ or $-1$, and indeed the variance then is 1. But at the second flip ($t=2$) the possible values are $2$, $0$ or $-2$, and the variance is equal to 2. For an infinite number of flips (at $t=\infty$, when the range of all possible values of $y$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$), the variance is infinite.

These two facts play havoc on trying to draw inferences about the distribution of $y$ (rather than $y_{t}$ for a given $y_{0}$) given only a sample when using the basic tools of statistical inference. (How can a finite $\bar{y}$ estimate *undefined*? How can a finite $s^{2}_{y}$ estimate $\sigma^{2}_{y}=\infty$?)

There are many kinds of random walk, and more generally, of autogregressive process (i.e. any variable that depends in some way on its previous values). The example here uses a simple Bernouli random variable (the coin toss), but one could:

- add a normally distributed random value to successive values of $y$ instead... or indeed a random value drawn from any sort of distribution;
- make the value of $y$ at some point in time depend on previous values of $y$ from more than one point in time (e.g. $y_{t} = y_{t-1} + y_{t-2} + \text{Something Random}$);
- pair the value of $y$ with a random value of $x$ to create a two-dimensional random walk;
- make $y_{t}$ some fancy *function* of $y_{t-1}$, a simple example is $y_{t} = \alpha y_{t-1} + \text{Something Random}$, where $|\alpha| < 1$, meaning that the memory of any specific moment of $y$ *decays* over time (with the memory lasting longer the closer $|\alpha|$ is to 1)—per Alecos' comments, this would simply be 'autoregressive' (a pure random walk would have $|\alpha|=1$);
- do lots of other things to make random walks and/or autoregressive processes more complex.

But they are all the Dickens to try and analyze using the basic methods. Which is why we have *cointegrating regressions* and *error correction models* and other time series analysis techniques for dealing with these kind of data (which we sometimes refer to as 'non-integrated', 'long-memoried' or 'unit root' among other labels, depending on the details).

The origin of the term "random walk" is from a pair of very brief letters to *Nature* in 1905.

**References**
Pearson, K. (1905). Letters to the Editor: The problem of the random walk. *Nature*, 72(1865):294.

Pearson, K. (1905). Letters to the Editor: The problem of the random walk. *Nature*, 72(1867):342.

Comment: You write "A random walk is a series of measurements in which the value at any given point in the series depends on values of the previous points in the series." But this describes any autoregressive process, and not all autoregressive processess are random walks. Since obviously you know the subject matter, I believe it would be helpful if you revised this statement in order to bring into the surface what is the unique characteristic(s) of a random walk.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos TY! Please help me out here... don't actually have that deep a familiarity with the subject. How would you suggest I differentiate random walks from autoregressive processes?

Comment: Gladly. There is a large literature on random walk(s), the subject is very diverse. But at the first level, what distinguishes a random walk is that _all_ past values of each step contribute with their _full_ value to the current value of their sum (which is the random walk).In an autoregressive process, usually the effect of the past gradually dies out. You essentially discuss this in your post Also now I re-read your answer, perhaps you want to re-think the use of the word "population": each $y_t$ has a different distribution, so in what sense $y_t, y_{t+1}...$ belong to the same population?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Thanks! So in your view only truly unit root processes are random walks, whereas, say, long-memoried processes should simply be described as autoregressive?

Comment: From what I have read, indeed, processes with "long-memory" are not classified as "random walks". On the other hand, long-memory processes are usually thought of as a category on their own, and they are not usually called "autoregressive".

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos So what is the category of processes encompassing short memoried processes, long memoried processes, and infinitely memoried processes? :) How are the edits reading now?

Comment: I don't think the nomenclature is that clear. The edits are fine, just one more thing that looks strange: why are you saying that the mean of the process is undefined? A few lines above you _assume_ that it has a starting value of zero. In that case, don't you think one can calculate the expected value? Random walks are usually defined in this way, with some starting value, zero or non-zero. "Arbitrary" is not a synonym for "undefined".

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I guess the econometrician who introduced me to the non-stationary time-series world framed it that way (specifically as "the mean is undefined"). Which do you think is more appropriate, "undefined" or "arbitrary"?

Comment: For a pure random walk (i.e. without drift, and with increments of mean zero), the mean will definitely exist and will be equal to the starting value. If you want to imagine a process that started in the infinite past, there are some issues to be taken care of in order to  interchange the expected value integral with the infinite sum, but the mean is _defined_.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I don't think the past has to be *infinite* for the mean to be undefined: just *unknown*.

Comment: We deal with unknown quantities, parameters, distributions etc, all the time in statistics and econometrics -everything then should be undefined. No. "Undefined" has a very specific mathematical meaning, and it does not apply here. Note that to say "started at the infinite past" is strictly speaking, wrong: nothing can "start" at infinity. Essentially we mean "it extends backwards infinitely". This is no different than "it extends forward infinitely".

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos To clarify: If we do not know where or how long ago the random walk started, how can we estimate the mean of the series since then? I don't think we can, and that's what I was trying to get at. Anywho: I very much appreciate your input here.

Comment: @Alexis thanks I learned the concept based on your comment , thanks

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos finally I could not understand what do really get from a random walk ?

Comment: @Nemo You get a specific type of behavior (usually over time): the past fully determines where you are -_but_, the evolution _path_ does not affect where you will be next. _How_ the process arrived at its current position, doesn't matter for the future.

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos Thanks for your comment. I have one question, the above answer is about what the random walk is but what a random walk does for GSEA? I see in that paper written that random walk is similar to Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. How they are similar ? actually there are over 1000 pages on web explaining the KS test but none of them is useful. They try to make it complicated rather than saying what is exactly doing. Can you please answer to my second question if you know ?

Comment: A random walk is really not "similar to a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test". A derivation of the asymptotic distribution of the K-S test statistic under the null hypothesis uses a notion related to a random walk. The point of drawing that connection seems from my quick look to be to motivate the development in the next section (the GSEA test). I'm not sure that was a good choice; it seems to have led you into confusion rather than helped you see what was going on. I suggest you try to understand random walks separately before trying to understand the connection between random walks and GSEA.

Comment: @Alexis Deliberately so -- with no "@" on it, Learner (whose comment mine is under) should have been notified automatically (as well as you, since you own the post the comment is under). My comment is very close to the limit of allowed characters as it stands.